# Jquery validation one at a time or together

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I took over a site that makes use of jquery.validation.min. I added 'required' to a group (or technically to the first in a group) of radio inputs.

Before I'd done this the error messages would show up beneath the inputs, in red. However, the error of the radio group behaves differently. It gets a tooltip and scrollTo while all other inputs remain untouched. Only after choosing one of the options do the other errors appear.

I would like the error message of the radio group to show up as a red box looks the rest of the inputs. I didn't find this behavior being declared anywhere so I'm assuming it has to do with default behaviors. How can I change this?

Comment: It would be smart to show us the relevant code for what you're talking about.

Comment: *"I would like the error message of the radio group to show up as a red box looks the rest of the inputs. I didn't find this behavior being declared anywhere so I'm assuming it has to do with default behaviors."* ~  There are no styles included with this plugin.  Any borders or colors you're seeing are defined in your own CSS alone based on classes that are simply toggled by this plugin.  You're going to have to write the question better and include enough relevant code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sparky I'm not referring to it's coloring per se. Indeed I found that declared on the page. I'm talking about it's behavior as a benign box underneath the element as opposed to the radio group which was treated individually, and as a tooltip. 

I do notice that the general JQuery has the tooltip and the validation.min uses the regular box.

Comment: There is no box either.  Again, that's all in your CSS.  By default, the plugin simply inserts a `label` element after the input element.   As far as any deviations from the default, it's impossible to know since you've shown us zero code.